# Why use requireJS instead of an ordered include list?

Tags: javascript, web, dependency-injection, requirejs, gruntjs

I've been using a grunt file to concatenate all my JS into a single file which is then sent to the client. What advantage do I have in using require calls then? The dependencies are inherent from the concatenation order and I don't have to muddy all my JS with extra code and another third-party library.

Further, backbone models (for example) clearly state their inheritance in their definitions. Not to mention that they simply wouldn't work if their dependencies weren't included anyway.

Also, wouldn't maintenance be easier if all comments related to dependencies were in one place (the grunt file) to prevent human error and having to open every JS file to understand its dependencies?

**EDIT**

My (ordered) file list looks something like:

```
....
files: [
    "js/somelib.js",
    "js/somelib2.js",
    "js/somelib3.js",
    "js/models.js",
    "js/views.js",
    "js/controllers.js",
    "js/main.js"
], ...
```

So perhaps requireJS isn't worth it for small projects anyway.

Comment: Especially In a large applications, concatenating all js files isnt desirable; it makes first access slow. Declaring dependencies where they are used is a lot easier to maintain,  and helps prevent sending clients js they'll never use - or worse thats obsolete and just dead   ytes.

Comment: You are referring to deferral or lazy loading of scripts which yes, makes sense for bigger projects. You say easier to maintain but you haven't said how it's easier. Maintaining code in multiple files instead of one sounds like more effort. Perhaps there is a way in requireJS to write the require dependencies in one file?.. More convenient?

Comment: Consider a project with 100 js files, you modify one to no longer depend on foo.js . Can you remove foo.js from the files array? That should highlight how managing dependencies where they are used is easier, and that problem can occur with a handful of js files. Note also that declaring dependencies where they are used and having a single-file production build are not mutually exclusive; and neither is using require.js or similar incompatible with what you are already doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the size of your app and the end use case..

- A single site.min.js payload for the front end (client) generally aims for small file sizes and simple architectures (1 single file generated from maybe 10).
- back end based (server) apps are usually much bigger and complicated and therefore may warrant the use of another tool to help with managing large code libraries and dependencies (50 files for example).

In general, RequireJS is worthwhile but only if you have many files and dependencies. An alternative for use in the client would be almond. Again, using a tool like this must warrant the need (many files and dependencies).

The answer from orourkedd is also worth reading.

Comment: This answer doesn't make a lot of sense - what does front and backend have to do with it?

Comment: edited to make more sense? Tried to explain the average use case of front vs backend dev.

Answer (score 1):

Using require.js allow you to break down each part of your application into reusable modules (AMD) and to manage those dependencies easily.  It is not easy to manage dependencies in a javascript application with 100 classes, for example.

Also, if you don't want all the overhead of require, check this out (developed by the same guy who created require.js): https://github.com/jrburke/almond

Comment: Yeah, you might want to use requireJS in development and almond in production, for example. I think Soundcloud do something like that.

Comment: What is easier in opening 100 files rather than 1 file that details the dependencies? Also, what happens when say 10 of those files all depend on the same file/library? Wouldn't it be worthwhile to know this in the build script for proper prioritisation?

Comment: Require.js will handle all of the prioritization for your using the optimizer.  Also, 100 classes could be 10,000+ lines of code in one file - not my thing during development.  I also compile my dust templates and wrap them in a `define` statement allowing them to be loaded with require.  Dozens of classes, templates, and external libraries in one file would be a nightmare imo.

Comment: Also, the `define` and `require` methods will automatically negotiate all the prioritization for you.  `define(['a', 'b', 'c'], ...)` tells require that a,b,c are required for the module.  The optimizer will place them in the one, large, minified, production file appropriately.

Comment: I appreciate your answers/comments. My scenario was probably not so obvious in the question above. You've helped me understand the use case much better and Almond looks promising for front end setups.